# Calling Javascript function inside JSP scriplet

Tags: javascript, jsp, scriptlet

I have a javascript function that needs to be called under a condition.

The condition is given below

```
<%if(request.getAttribute("isValidUser").equals("false"))
  {%>
     Redirect();
<%}%>
```

`Redirect()` is the function name that I have declared and defined in the  section.

When I execute the page I am getting the following error.

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred 
    processing JSP page /HomePage.jsp at line 136
```

HomePage.jsp:

```
133:      <p><input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/></p>
134:      <span id="nullPassword" class="error"></span>
135:   </div><span style="color:red;">
136:   <%if(request.getAttribute("isValidUser").equals("false"))
137:   {%>
138:        Redirect();
139:   <%}%>
```

Please help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide the full stacktrace. Or is that the only message that was logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough rep points to comment, but it looks like your js function call should be in script tags.

Answer (score 1):

[getAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) returns an object and you may need to typecast.

**On another note:**

Javascript and JSP are two different things. JSPs will undergo a compilation process just like your Java files. Only if the compilation is successful, the JSP can be "reached".

Javascript on the other hand will execute on the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Put the javascript function call within  tags

```
 <%

 if(request.getAttribute("isValidUser").equals("false"))

 { 

 %>

   <script>Redirect();</script>

 <%

 }

%>
```